# How to deal with JSON Objects containing Bad ID's

Tags: javascript, json, object

After fetching a json object from an external API I get the following as an example:

```
id: 1
name: john
email: something@example.com
3a5411a124378534906a883a0c5ccda5724175eb: USA
```

So, in JavaScript I can easily access: object.id, object.name, etc.

However, object.3a5411a124378534906a883a0c5ccda5724175eb throws the error:

> Identifier directly after number

How do deal with a situation like that? Or, in other words, how can I get the value of USA?

Comment: There's nothing "bad" about that ID. Just use `object["3a5411a124378534906a883a0c5ccda5724175eb"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
object["3a5411a124378534906a883a0c5ccda5724175eb"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the for-in loop on object to access all the properties of objects  as follows event the properties like you mention,

```
var obj = {
id: 1,
name: 'john',
email: 'something@example.com',
'3a5411a124378534906a883a0c5ccda5724175eb': 'USA'
}
for(var prop in obj){
//do the stuff here what you want for each properties
    console.log(obj[prop]);
}
```